# What is the data structure of Iterator object? Why it doesn't contain values?

Tags: javascript

I tried the following code to view the data structure of Iterator object. It just prints `object { }`

```
    var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    var iterator = array1.keys(); 
    console.log(iterator); // object { } 
    console.log(iterator.toString()); // "[object Array Iterator]"
```

Comment: You're confusing the iterator with the thing it's iterating over. Don't say one when you mean the other.

Comment: just use the array length like this: `for (var i; i<array1.length; i++) {console.log(i)}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `spread operator (...)` for this. What it does is, it  allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded.

Read more about spread syntax [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Something like

```js
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var iterator = array1.keys(); 
console.log(...iterator);
```